# How can I find the IP destination of a Linked Server

Tags: sql

I have a linked Oracle Server on my SQL Server 2005 server.
I need to change to where the linked server points to, as they have conducted a failover test.

Comment: `tnsping` should be able to tell you that.

Comment: I have only tried to see the properties of the linked Server, and also failed to run a stored procedure. SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (
         myLinkedServer, 
         'SELECT
             @@SERVERNAME AS TargetServerName,
             SUSER_SNAME() AS ConnectedWith,
             DB_NAME() AS DefaultDB,
             client_net_address AS IPAddress
          FROM
              sys.dm_exec_connections
          WHERE
              session_id = @@SPID
        ')

Comment: Just asking: If you are linking to a failover cluster, shouldn't you link to the SID rather than the IP?